# Mocking Flask's `send_from_directory` for testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, mocking, python-unittest

I’m using `unittest` to test a Flask application, which is written for Python 3.5. I have a `static` directory that contains HTML files that will be embedded by our clients. Based on which client the request is coming from, I add different headers (CORS, CSP, etc.).

The endpoint looks like this:

```
@app.route('/embed/<path:filename>', methods=['GET']):
def embed_static(filename):
    response = flask.send_from_directory(app.config['EMBED_DIR'], filename)

   # Do the header magic here

   return response
```

…and I wrote a test for it:

```
def test_embed_static(self):
    with unittest.mock.patch('flask.send_from_directory') as mocked:
        page = app.test_client().get('/embed/test/index.html')

    self.assertTrue(mocked.called)
```

The last assertion always fails. `unittest.mock.patch` works like charm in other tests.

Am I overlooking something, or is this a special case I don’t know about?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the `return_value` of the mock object before you make the test api call. After changing your code into the following, it works:

```
def test_embed_static(self):
    with unittest.mock.patch('flask.send_from_directory') as mocked:
        mocked.return_value = "Test Mock"
        page = app.test_client().get('/embed/test/index.html')

    self.assertTrue(mocked.called)
```